# Перегрузка "=" для контейнера STL

Tags: c++

Нужно перегрузить оператор "="  (присваивания для следующих типов данных)

```
enum Suit { clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades };

vector< Suit > CardSuit[];

Suit su = Suit(1);
CardSuit[0] = su; <-  чтобы работало так????
```

Comment: Возможно, на второй строчке квадратные скобки лишние...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector<Suit> CardSuit[];
```

Это что-то странное - вы объявляете `CardSuit` как массив векторов, так что `CardSuit[0]` - это вектор, а вы присваиваете ему отдельный элемент.

Чтобы работало так, как вы хотите - нужно сделать `CardSuit` вектором с уже выделенным как минимум нулевым элементом, типа

```
vector<Suit> CardSuit(1);
```

Или, что разумнее -

```
vector<Suit> CardSuit;
```

и добавлять

```
CardSuit.push_back(su);
```